# C# UWP Download into AppData: Access Denied

Tags: c#, uwp, windowsiot, appdata, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm writing code for an app which runs on a Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT.
I am developing via Remote on Visual Studio 2017.

I have to download a .zip file via REST and save it into the AppData-Folder.
But I am getting this Exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Access to the path 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\f6e0d540-943b-4fd7-9d4e-1572ca85cec2VS.Debug_ARM.knhelfen\htmls5000\myZipDownload.zip' is denied.
```

The download works fine if I change the downloadpath into another folder than AppData.

This is my downloadmethod:

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(this.url);
            HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            getRequest.Method = this.method;
            getRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + (this.bearerToken);
            response3 = await getRequest.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream fileStream = response3.GetResponseStream();

            //Download .zip file to downloadPath
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Yield();
                using (var path = File.Create(downloadPath + "/myZipDownload.zip"))
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(path);
                }
            });
```

Comment: better if you'd write: using(var fileStream = response3.GetResponseStream()){...}.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Set folder permissions for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils).

And try to use CreateFile2 API to the folder.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203305/my-application-has-no-rights-on-any-folder) is a similar question you can reference.